# Why is Java forcing me to initialize my String before letting the user input the value of the String?

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner, variable-initialization

I'm essentially making a small, simply "twenty questions" style program, using nested if-statements to try to guess what object the user is thinking based on clarifying questions.
I'm using the if statements to eventually give the user a "result" at the end, using a String variable called "result".

**My ultimate confusion** lies in which the compiler is stating that "`variable response may have not been initialized`". To which, based on the code, I would think it *is* after the if statements.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoQuestions {
  public static void main (String args[] ) {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    String answer1, answer2, response;

    System.out.println("\n[Two Questions]\nThink of an object, and I'll try to guess it.");
    System.out.println("Is it an \"animal\", a \"vegetable\", or a \"mineral\"? (Type an answer exactly as quoted)");
    answer1 = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Is it bigger than a breadbox? (yes/no)");
    answer2 = kb.nextLine();

    // example "response" based on user decisions
    if (answer1 == "animal" || answer1 == "Animal") {
      response = "yes";
      if (answer2 == "yes" || answer2 == "Yes") {
        response = "squirrel";
      }
    }
    // more if statements...

    // final machine "response" to user"
    // TODO: Figure out why *this* "response" requires initialization before if statements.
    System.out.println("My guess is that you are thinking of a " + response + ".\nI would ask you if I'm right, but I don't actually care.");

  }
}
```

Comment: What if I input the string `"potato"`? Which of your if statements will initialize `response` in that case?

Comment: There may be a situation where none of your `if` conditions are true. In that case, what will be the value of variable `response`? In other words, you need at least one `else` block. Alternatively, you can initialize `response` before the first `if` statement.

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare `String`s, use `String#equals` or even [`String#equalsIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))

Comment: "What if I input the string "potato"? Which of your if statements will initialize response in that case?"
None of them would

Comment: Precisely!!  That's why you are getting a compilation error.   The compiler needs to be sure that ALL possible paths to the point where you use the local variable are going to initialize it.  (And the compiler is using simple rules to make the decision ... not the high-level theorem proving capability of a human mind.)

Comment: Ok, so I used similar code (modified thanks to @Silvio Mayolo and @Steven C, I understand response wouldn't be initialized in certain circumstances now), but I replaced the `==` with `String.equals` as per @MadProgrammer 's suggestion. It works, but now I'm curious as to why *this* works, and using the equality statements do not. Normally, this does work, but with nested if statements, it doesn't.

Maybe a better question would be, why should Strings be compared to using the `equals` method rather than the `==` comparison operator? Is it because Strings are objects and not truly primitive?

Comment: You must have changed something else as well as `==` -> `equals`.

Comment: Could've, I assume. Maybe the night is long. I'll try to rewrite using the `==` comparison and see if I get different results.

Comment: Okay, so now I've rewritten the same program. I can confirm, when I use the `equals` method to compare the Strings, the desired generated  response will occur in the final `println` statement. When I use the `==` comparison operator, it defaults to the `else` statement I added in. My assumption of what is happening is that Java has no real way of comparing the Strings appropriately within a different scope (?) using operators.

Comment: the String can be initialized with the default response value in case none of the if blocks pass, or an else block can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Like mad programmer said use String equals function to compare string.
2. Yes it will need to be initialize before compilation can take place. If Im not wrong you can initialize with Null, or " ", empty string.

Comment: Too funny! I'm going to throw that term once in a while as a joke to my mates.